# Locating user input from a form and assigning it to a property

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have a form, that takes user[name, age, photo], as inputs of type text.
I want to locate it the input in the HTML and then assign it to a property;

```
newProductData.name = $('#new-product-name').val;
```

I used this, but newProduct.name, doesn't get assigned the value, which would be say for instance "ibrahim". How would I go about getting the string value entered into the form, and assigning it as a property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call the function actually instead of just referencing it. Add `()`:

```
newProductData.name = $('#new-product-name').val();
```